# Excel matching 2 columns by text and numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, formula, vlookup

I have 2 excel tables with data and i want from table 1 to get the item number and add it to table 2 based on item description thats contained in table 1 column itemName2.

Table1 data:
[image]

Table2 data:

[image: table2]

Expected result should look like this:
[image: result]
last column added based on formula that matches text from itemName2 in both tables, but not exact match - text in table2 columns is partly in itemName2 from table 1

Markdown data:
table1

| Location | ItemName2 | Height | Width | itemid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7-04-01-A | U 104 ST9 | 2 | 23 |  |
| 7-04-01-B | U 708 ST9 | 2 | 23 |  |
| 7-04-01-C | H 1145 ST10 | 2 | 23 |  |
| 7-04-01-D | H 1733 ST9 | 2 | 23 |  |
| 7-04-02-A | U 108 ST9 | 2 | 23 |  |
| 7-04-02-B | U 727 ST9 | 2 | 23 |  |
| 7-04-02-C | H 1146 ST10 | 2 | 23 |  |
| 7-04-02-D | H 2033 ST10 | 2 | 23 |  |
| 7-04-12-C | H 1277 ST9 | 2 | 23 |  |

table2

| 24744/1277 | ABS Кант EGGER | H 1277 ST9 акация лейкленд све | 0,8 | 23 | 75000 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24722/1277 | ABS Кант EGGER | H 1277 ST9 акация лейкленд све | 2,0 | 23 | 75000 |
| 24550/1312 | 43мм.ABS Кант EGGER | H 1312 ST10 Дъб Уайт. Пяс. Беж | 2,0 | 43 | 75000 |
| 24558/1312 | ABS кант EGGER | H 1312 ST10 Дъб Уайт. Пяс. Беж | 2,0 | 23 | 75000 |
| 24565/1312 | ABS кант EGGER | H 1312 ST10 Дъб Уайт. Пяс. Беж | 0,8 | 23 | 75000 |
| 24550/1313 | 43мм.ABS Кант EGGER | H 1313 ST10 Дъб Уайтр. Сивокаф | 2,0 | 43 | 75000 |
| 24558/1313 | ABS кант EGGER | H 1313 ST10 Дъб Уайтр. Сивокаф | 2,0 | 23 | 75000 |

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you add markdown sample data so we won't have to type this ourselves? Also, can you explain how the two would match in your highlighted cells? They are two different values.

Comment: Included link for both tables, dont know how to add "markdown sample", and yes i do explain that the data in table 1 is partly in table 2, not exact match to be found. Thats the issue, otherwise its easy to do.

Comment: I can see it's not an exact match but did you meant to say that the values in the red squares are somewhat the same? If so, please do explain in what way and what rules you'd use yourself in theory to match the two together. Markdown sample data can be generated for example [here](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/).

Comment: i would use the code - 104 st9 and check where it is contained in the other table itemName2 column, but first of all since the items have 2 with same description but different dimension i will filter both tables so they display only items with same height. I added markdown data, but i dont know why its displayed like this, on the post it doesnt look like that but when i post it it messes up..

Comment: I still don't see any match between the table contents as given. To fix the format try adding a blank line before the table markdown text

Comment: Check now, there is. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to understand the query as best as possible but I still see little to none resemblences. Either way, try the following:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=XLOOKUP(B2&" *",I$1:I$7,G$1:G$7,"",2)
```

Or, a classic `INDEX()` `MATCH()` combo:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(G$1:G$7,MATCH(B2&" *",I$1:I$7,0)),"")
```

As you can see, the only match was generated on row 10 with the current sample data.

Comment: That solves it all, very much appreciated!!!